# How to remove grid/graph lines while using zoom in orthographic view?

Tags: orthographic

I'm working with a 2D cad model and need to zoom in and out a lot to make sure what I'm editing is still similar to another part of the model. When I zoom in i'm getting these white graph/grid lines and was wondering if there was a way to remove them or make them lighter as I don't need them.

[image: image of grid lines]

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the smart way to do it, but I managed to remove the lines:

1. opened side panel
2. set scale to 0